# Reasons for didReceiveRemoteNotification to not run?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently I'm working with Firebase for push notifications in Swift. I want to retrieve the data attached to a sent notification.

I've been using the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` function in my app delegate, however, this function never seems to run.

I've created a test within the delegate so that a label changes when it fires, but it hasn't fired once. I have tried with the app closed, in the background and in the foreground.

Breakpoints also suggest that it doesn't fire in the foreground.

If anyone could shed light on what specifications need to be met in order for this function to fire, that would be great.

Finally, my code for the testing is as follows.

Code in AppDelegate.swift:

```
private func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [String : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler:(UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    //vc is the ViewController.swift
    vc.updateLabel()

}
```

Code in ViewController.swift

```
func updateLabel() {

    notificationLabel.text = "The function has fired"

}
```

Thanks.

Edit - Additional functions from my delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Use Firebase library to configure APIs
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
    print("FCM token: \(token ?? "")")

    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    print(Messaging.messaging().apnsToken!)

    let notificationType = UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings!.types

    if Messaging.messaging().fcmToken != nil {

        print(Messaging.messaging().fcmToken!)
        Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/news")

    }
}

func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {

    let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token()!
    print("Instance ID Token: \(refreshedToken)")

    connectToFCM()

}

func connectToFCM() {

    let notificationType = UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings!.types
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true

}
```

Comment: Are you registering to receive notifications and are you sending the device token to firebase?

Comment: I've updated the question with more functions from my delegate to show the full process of the initial connection to Firebase.

Comment: I should also mention that the notifications are coming through fine from the Firebase console, it's just the issue of this function not running right now.

Comment: Which version of ios did you try?

Comment: I've been testing it on iOS 10